# Is the existence of a mixed branch of Indo-European plausible?

Tags: historical-linguistics, linguistic-typology, indo-european, language-families

I was thinking about the possible existence of a branch of the Indo-European family that combines features of several branches.

For example, a branch that is something in between the Germanic and the Balto-Slavic one. It might be a strange question to ask, but this piqued my curiosity.

Comment: It's a reasonable question. The relationships among the various languages is not entirely established, and some groupings (for example, Italo-Celtic) are not universally accepted by scholars. Furthermore, even if we could go back in time and find a group of people speaking proto-Germanic or proto-Greek, or whatever, these people would live in a real world of language contact, and there might be regions where there was some mixing.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's your motivation for asking this?

Comment: Every branch of IE has features in common with other branches, so the question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: English is a mixed language combining Germanic and Romance features and vocabulary.

Comment: @curiousdannii Vocabulary: OK, but which Romance features absent from Germanic are in English?

Comment: @jknappen I can't remember the details, but I'm pretty sure I've seen people say we've borrowed more than strictly just vocab.

Comment: @curiousdannii OK, one can argue on some phonologocal features being clearly borrowed from Norman French (the /v/ sound, maybe also /ʒ/) but those features come from borrowing vocabulary and not naturalising it.

Answer (score 6):

#### Yes, depending on your definition of "combining features"

First, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages#/media/File:IndoEuropeanTree.svg)'s a good 'tree' of many languages in the Indo-European category.

See how many languages there are? And this doesn't even have many dialects on it (for example, it has Irish but not subdivided into Connacht, Munster, Ulster, etc.).

Now consider that this is just one possible organization. There are many languages that include words/grammar generally associated with one language family but not another.

Let's talk about [Italo-Celtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italo-Celtic). Italo-Celtic is a proposed grouping of the Italic (Latin and other Romance languages mostly) and the Celtic (Gaelic, Welsh, Breton, etc.) languages.

These are completely different groups, so why are they considered similar? They share some of the same characteristics, such as a long i (ī) in the genitive (2nd declension for Latin, female 2nd for Irish), similar superlative suffixes (ismo, em), and a merging of the aorist and perfect tenses. There's also some vocabulary, but [similar words aren't quite as convincing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42817/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-words-night-and-eight) as grammar and morphology.

### This likely is the result of a Proto-Italo-Celtic language that both of the subgroups descended from.

But Italo-Celtic is more a supergroup than an in-between group. Are there any real "in-the-middle" branches?

The answer is no under the current classification scheme, mainly due to the fact that that makes no sense. The goal of a classification is for everything to fit neatly into a category, so the categories are pretty broad. You won't find anything that's quite in-between groups, though there are plenty of languages like [Albanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_language) that are grouped in their own category.

Generally, when linguists find related languages that aren't quite the same, they group them into another Indo- group. Indo-Iranian (containing Indo-Aryan and Iranian groupings) and Balto-Slavic (with Baltic and Slavic groupings) are good examples. Instead of having languages that are part of both groups, they subdivide the groupings closer and call them 'cousins'.

This goes to show that all of our beautiful classification scheme is only mortal and not infallible. With the way languages work, any geographically close languages may undergo some mixing. Linguistic categories today aren't necessarily the same in a couple centuries, or millennia.

So, mixed branches definitely exist, but it all depends on what time period you're in and what classification scheme you're using.

Comment: "…a long i (ī) in the genitive plurals (2nd and 3rd declensions for Latin…)" genitive singular, and first and second declensions, surely? The second and third genitive plural are _-ōrum_ and _-um_.

Comment: @Draconis whoops I was thinking of dative, sorry. Fixed. Also, isn't the first declension -ae?

Comment: I believe it developed from earlier -a-i (i.e. a suffix -i plus the thematic vowel), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @jknappen look some of the pronouns and verbs in turkish vs hungarian, they're pretty similar in some cases. [Googling pulled up this result pretty quick](http://archive.worldhistoria.com/turkish-and-hungarian-language-simmilarities_topic14451.html).

Comment: M-T-pronouns https://wals.info/feature/136A#2/24.8/153.8 are not good to prove a specific relationship between Hungarian and Turkish: They are also in Indogermanic, Georgian, and some other languages, And they are of course also in Finnish.

Comment: @jknappen I've removed it anyway, as that was only tangentially related to OP's original question.

Comment: *This likely happened when a certain group of conquerors speaking Latin invaded Gaul and Britannia, bringing their language with them* -- the Italo-Celtic theory is that Italic and Celtic both descend from a common subbranch of IE, not that the shared features result from an Italic superstrate due to conquest.

Comment: @TKR thanks, I'm not familiar with the theory so I just assumed.

Comment: In fact, the discovery of Tocharian has significantly weakened the support for Italo-Celtic

Comment: Several common features of Italic and Celtic are now just considered common archaism instead of common innovations.

Comment: For the interaction of Romance and Celtic, see also this question and its answers https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29660/which-romance-language-retains-the-most-words-from-celtic

Answer (score 4):

In fact, it looks like all major branches of Indo-Germanic came into existence out of a language continuum at one time. All proposals for subgrouping (except the well-established groups Indo-Iranian and Balto-Slavic) have little to no support. [This picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages#/media/File:Indo-European_isoglosses.png) shows some overlapping features between different branches of Indo-Germanic.

So, the existence of a now extinct branch of Indo-Germanic that lies between two established branches is totally plausible.

Comment: Balto-Slavic is not well established I don't think. There are few experts, so it's not mainstream for starters, and each with their own theory, so there's only a rough consensus about the similarities, but not the origin (or *the origin**s*** one has to say in spirit of the questioner).

Comment: The time depth of indo-aryan poses a different problem and leaves a lot of questions.

Comment: @vectory: Proto-Balto-Slavic is reconstructable and reconstructed, and a Balto-Slavic branch is also clearly seen in all dendrograms of Indogermanic I have ever seen. For more information look at this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balto-Slavic_languages

Comment: @vectory What problems do you see in the time depth of Indo-Aryan?

Comment: You have old parts of the rich vedas that are hard to date or decipher. Then you have Avestan supposedly 2000 years younger, another lithurgical piece, not necessarily common (vulgar) vernacular, and old Persian. That's no complete picture. The role of Mitanni in this would be interesting, though there's not much to say as far as I'm aware. On the other hand, the origin of the Indo-Aryans is highly debatable of course. Genetic relation based solely on linguistic evidence is a bit iffy. Hhowever, I don't really doubt the classification, I'm just well curious.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest there are probably many historical languages which combined characteristics of various modern language groups, and this wouldn't even need to be the result of mixing, it would simply be that those languages either died out, or changed into modern language groups. As a Biologist, I'll give a Biological example: dinosaurs combined characteristics of modern reptiles and modern birds (e.g. - feathers and teeth), not because they were the result of breeding between ancient birds and ancient reptiles, but because all three groups shared an ancestor. So, to continue with the example of Italo-celtic used by other answers, I don't see why there couldn't have been a historical language with a mix of modern Italic and modern Celtic features. A real example is that Latin contains features found in modern German, such as the three grammatical genders, which are not found in modern Italic languages.

Comment: The three genders of Latin and German are a shared old feature going back to proto-Indogermanic (perhaps to the state after the separation of the Anatolic branch containing the Hittite language)

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't consider it a feature of Italic languages (although I know Romanian has some kind of neuter nouns), just as I wouldn't consider teeth to be a feature of birds. I guess it depends whether you're using modern or historical languages as your reference point.

Comment: Unlike biological species, languages cannot only diverge but also converge. The result of linguistic convergence is called a *sprachbund*.

Comment: "*an ancestor*" I didn't know dinosauroids procreated asexually. To lend another example from biology: The Liger is a *cross* of a male lion and a female tiger; A mule is a *hybrid* of f. horse and m. donkey; Mestizo Mexicans are a mix of Europeans and Mesoamericans. A "Liliger" is the mix of a Liger and a lion. If one side of the mix outproportions the other side over many generations, you basically get Spanish with almost no trace of Aztek, Incan, Taino but saying it was straight Spanish is, maybe, overly simplistic.

Comment: @vectory Biological hybrids are only possible between closely related species and they often have significant problems to reproduce (like the sterile mules you mentioned). A *sprachbund* can contain genetically unrelated languages.

Comment: On the other hand infertile hybrids, e.g. male Liger, will not survive, unviable hybrids won't even live. A "Spaztek" branch maintaining the proportion in a stable branch is unlikely. But they either didn't share an ancestor, or we at least don't know it (though there are tentative suggestions linking e.g. Alaskan-Aleute and Indo-European). The Diamond Problem for Multiple Inheritance in software Engineering comes to mind: Classifying e.g. amphibious vehicle; One solution is to inherite traits instead of base classes. Creole and pidgeon language has subtleties in the classification, too.

Comment: @vectory One of the most well-known linguistic hybrids is in fact English, at least what the vocabulary is concerned. It ancestors are Anglo-Saxon, Norman French, and Old Danish (not counting the Greco-Latin vocabulary borrowed later)

Comment: English is more of a Chimera. And then there's the process of grafting (in 2009 transgenes were found). Anyhow, biology metaphors only go so far. The thing is that continuity is defined as unbroken inheritance. Do we see repair around breakage or what else would you look for?

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that there are two ways for languages to share features: through common descent (homologous features) or through mixing, and outside influence, and the two need to be considered separately.

Comment: And I tried to point out the diamond inheritance that's both or neither.